# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-2024 or swt-motif-2024 in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, swt

When running a maven build using the maven surefire plugin I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library:
no swt-pi4-gtk-4934r6 in java.library.path
    no swt-pi4-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /user_directory/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi4-gtk-4934r6.so
    Can't load library: /user_directory/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi4-gtk.so
```

When trying to run integration tests. When I go to /user_directory/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/ on our linux server I see several libswt-pi3-gtk-xxx.so but no pi4. Is there a way to have it use the pi3 swt that are already available. It's a company server so I can't add external software to it.

It's grabbing swt plugins from https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06/202006171000/plugins/ so its grabbing the 3.114.100 version of org.eclipse.swt plugins.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

CentOS? Install gtk using `yum install gtk3`, it will provide loading of swt.